# Arrays and ListView in Android

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have a ListView that displays every item in an array called, "Facts_Array". What I would like to do is display the count of the item clicked on. Right now I have this:

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

When an item is clicked  in the listview, it displays it using Toast. What I would like to change is what the toast displays. I would like it to find the number in which the item comes. If I click on the second item in the list, I want it to display number 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ":D "+(position+1),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! That was a lot easier than I thought it would be!

Comment: Yep. "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes" - says stackoverflow